# R: Using object's name to print what is inside the object

Tags: r, string, object

My question is a basic one concerning object type manipulation.

```
hello = 3
name = 'hello'
```

I'm looking for a function that allows me to find the value 3 by using only the object name.

Something like:

```
print.the.thing.called(name)
[1] 3
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get` to get an object by its name :

```
R> x <- 2
R> get("x")
[1] 2
```